# Export tar of changed files in container

Tags: docker

I'm running containers using Docker. I'm making snapshots of the state of the container's filesystem as a diff from the container's base using `docker commit`. I would like to also snapshot in a tar file that stores just the files that have changed for the commit.

Using `docker diff` I can see which files have changed. Using `docker export` I get all files in the container in a tar. How do I get a tar file of just the changed files from the base? Ideally I could also exclude directories (like `/dev`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tarball is exactly what is stored within the Docker registry!

If the snapshot that you are interested in is already in a registry, you can use the [Docker Registry Protocol](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/api/registry_api/) to retrieve it.

If it is present only locally, you can look in `/var/lib/docker/graph/<imageid>/layer`: the changed files are here. Note that this location might change in Docker 0.7, since it is currently here as an artifact of the AUFS implementation.